# Adding new column to a pandas dataframe and inserting data corresponding to the existing data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which has columns like this.

Columns: [jobId, trainingInput, createTime, startTime, endTime, state, trainingOutput, etag, errorMessage, labels].

The trainingInput is a dictionary where I am stripping part of the data and creating a new column 'serviceAccount' to the dataframe. I am getting random data in the new column.

Dataframe sample:

```
trainingInput = {'scaleTier': 'CUSTOM', 'masterType': 'n2-highmem-4', 'packageUris': ['gs:/marketprice_aitp-0.0.0.tar.gz'] 'pythonVersion': '3.7', 'serviceAccount': 'projects/kk1'}
```

the serviceAccount should  be - 'projects/kk1' and should be inserted to the corresponding trainingInput.

```
**Expected output:**
trainingInput                                  serviceAccount
{'scaleTier': 'CUSTOM', 'masterType':           projects/kk1
 'n2-highmem-4', 'packageUris': 
['gs:/marketprice_aitp-0.0.0.tar.gz'] 
'pythonVersion': '3.7', 
'serviceAccount': 'projects/kk1'}
```

But what I am getting is random data for serviceAccount based on the code below.

```
k_1  = df['trainingInput'].values
    temp =[]
    for i in k_1:
        m= json.dumps(i)
        k = json.loads(m)
        temp.append(k['serviceAccount'])
        try:
                df5 =pd.DataFrame(temp)
              #  df.merge(pd.DataFrame(data=[df5.values] * len(df), columns=df5.index, #index=df.index), left_index=True, right_index=True)
                df['serviceaccount'] =k['serviceAccount']
                # df['region'] = k['region']
        except KeyError:
                df['serviceaccount'] = 'None'
```

I tried the merge commented here as well. But I get the error "ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)". Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: It would be most helpful if you could show as a sample of your data, and based on that sample, the output dataframe that you wnat to achieve.

Comment: I have added the expected input and output to the question.